# html5 audio gui development

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I am on the 11th level of my game (plan to have 20-25) and listening to the music that is going to be on the game, over and over, to see if it fits while testing it.

Now I've decided it is time to start working on the media player for it.

I plan to have all the songs on a loop. You can skip songs or go previous and play/pause. There also will be a button to mute.

I know how to add the GUI to the screen and use the mouse clicks to trigger methods. Just wondering what is the most used way instead of building it from nothing and wasting time.

I am just wondering if there a tut/guide as I plan on pulling an all-nighter to do this.
I'm in college but it's summer so decided this would be great for my portfolio.

Here's a [demo vid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Vwyqo_y_A&feature=youtu.be) of it. It is my first game so go easy! :)

Comment: This does look fun...

Comment: +1 for an interesting looking game concept. I'd be interested in trying it out once it is all finished :)

Comment: For anyone that wants the link when it's finished email at wayne.daly@mycit.ie with slimedrop in title and il send an email when its done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`<audio>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio). It has functions such as `.play()` and `.pause()`. To switch tracks, you'd modify the `src` to point to a different audio file, much in the same way you'd switch the `src` of an `<img>` tag to display a different image.

EDIT: I just watched video and I want to play this thing. The twist on the normal platformer (all the platforms being ones that you slowly fall through) could either be really awesome or really frustrating. I'm leaning towards awesome but that remains to be seen!

Comment: How would you know when a audio file has finished playing? And thanks yeah I wanted to make something you would need some skill to play, I added way more so far :)

Comment: I'm not sure on that; there may be an event for it. I've not had the opportunity to use the `<audio>` element yet.